# adding rel attribute to image link in a node

Tags: theming, nodes, media

I have a few images in a node that can be opened in a fancybox lightbox. I would like to link those images together to create a gallery. To do so I need to add a rel attribute to my image link. How can I do this?

I tried editing the field.tpl.php template, but without any luck.

Help would really be appreciated.

Comment: You probably want hook_preprocess_link().

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction how I do that?

Comment: Are you familiar with hooks?

Comment: No I'm afraid not. I only have knowledge of html, css & js...

Comment: In your theme folder you have a file called 'template.php', here is where you implement 'hooks' on the theme layer to override core functionality. Have a look at http://origin-api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/group/hooks/7 then have a look at this example http://drupalcode.org/project/icon.git/blob/67a5ae8a9799700f7e3862562f930ca6fe0b734a:/modules/icon_menu/icon_menu.module of how someone has used hook_preprocess_link in their module.

Comment: I'm trying to edit the above example but with no succes. I know it's much to ask, but could you have a go at it?

I got the template in the right place, and got the hook ready. I just can't figure out how to write the actual code

Comment: You can try http://drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter and forge your own image tag

Answer (score 1):

> I need to add a rel attribute to my image link. How can I do
>   this?

You can add a data attribute to your link in l() function:

```
// your image
$image = array(
    'style_name' => 'the name of the image style',
    'path' => 'relative path to your image',
    'alt' => '',
    'title' => '',
    'attributes' => array('class' => array('some_class'))
);

// link elements
$text = theme('image_style', $image); // in your case it's an image
$path = 'link_url';
$options = array(
    'attributes' => array(
        'class' => array('some_link_class'), 
        'rel' => 'some_relation'
    ),
    'html' => true
);

$link =  l($text, $path, $options);
```

**result:**

```
<a class="some_link_class" rel="some_relation" href="/your_site/link_url">
    <img src="path to your image style" class="some_class" typeof="foaf:Image">
</a>
```